# Problem ending programmatically an activity right after setting SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

The problem I have now seems so basic that someone else must have faced it before me.

Here is the code, it just saves some preferences to be used later on:

```
val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences!!.edit()
editor.putString("activeFolder", "FavoriteFolder")
editor.commit()
//finish()
```

Before that *sharedPreferences* is declared at the class level like this:

```
private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
```

An it is initialized inside *onCreate()*:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ....
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyNiceApp", MODE_PRIVATE)
    ....
}
```

After the code is executed I quit the activity by tapping the *back button* and all is good.

Finally here is the use case causing trouble. In the situation where there is nothing else to do after saving the preferences, instead of having the user manually tapping the *back button* I want the activity to automatically terninate and for that I call finish() (commented out in the code above). When doing that the activity closes as expected, but for some unknown reason the new preferences are not taken into account.

What do I need to do change to solve this issue?

Comment: is your function is on separate threads? Finish() just execute before actually setting up pref?

Comment: Might be a overhead issue especially to save a lot of data. Better run it on a different thread and sleep a bit before finishing the activity.

Comment: Nothing is on a separate thread here.

Comment: @Darkman. You mean put the finish() on a diffferent thread or the pref saving? Or both?

Comment: @Michel Saving and sleeping on a different thread and finish() on the main thread of course. Just use a handler I guess. If you familiar with synchorizations, then use it, but it is not needed in your case I think. Don't forget to `join()`! -- wait for the thread to finish its job.

Comment: I tried something like that with coroutines and failed.

Answer (score 0):

call this

```
editor.apply()
```

you can remove

```
edit.commit()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But changing editor.commit() to editor.apply() does not make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: try this for declare the variable
`private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences`

and here how you use the sharedPreferences

`with(sharedPreferences.edit()){
 putString("myString", "ini stringku")
 apply()
 }`

Comment: I tried and it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and learned something at the same time.

I was reading the new value of the sharedPreferences ("activeFolder") inside onCreate() but it appears that the onCreate() of the parent activity is not called after a finish().

Reading the new value of the sharedPreferences inside onStart() instead of inside onCreate() solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I cant see any problem from your code, but I guess the code omitted may block your finish action? So you can print some log before and after your `finish()`, and see whether it has been executed.

Comment: After automatically leaving the activity with finish() the preferences seems to be forgotten, but if I close the app and restart (or even go back to the activity) and get  out with the back button (without touching the preferences)) then all is OK. I even noticed some cases where all is OK directly. I seems somewhat unstable.

Comment: I can put some trace before and after finish(), but I already know that the preferences are set at some point because they come to what I expect them, but only later. Instead of being ready as soon as finish() has done its job of leaving the activity.